# Can't update numpy in Enthought Canopy 1.2

Tags: numpy, enthought, canopy

I just updated Canopy to 1.2 via the Canopy app on OS X Mavericks, I only have the OS X Python and Enthought installed. I then went into Canopy package manager and updated all packages. But some packages still show updates as available including numpy. Clicking the install button to take me from 1.7.1 to 1.8 has no effect.

When I run ipython notebook:
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
I get:
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 9 but this version of numpy is 7

Clean install has no effect either, I'm still on numpy 1.7. Can't find anything via google or the Canopy kb.

Any ideas?

Comment: Solved it myself. I hadn't done a totally clean install. I needed to delete Canopy.app from Applications folder AND /User/Library/Enthought. Clean install, all works.

Comment: glad that you are all set. For the reference of others, the disadvantage of doing this is that one loses any third party package installs or updates that one has previously done. Updates to the canopy application should not require any changes to one's user python environment. As I mentioned in my answer,  this bug is fixed in canopy 1.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry,this is a bug in the package manager which is fixed In canopy 1.3, to be released at the end of the month. In the meantime, the easiest work around is the counter intuitive step of uninstalling numpy (or, in general, any similarly misbehaving package) in the package manager. We will write a Knowledge Base article explaining this, and post the link here.

Comment: The Knowledge Base article can be found here: https://support.enthought.com/entries/26196695-Package-Manager-offers-update-but-won-t-install-it